# How does a non-EU spouse get his residence permit?

Tags: schengen, sweden, eu-citizens, residency, spouses

I am a Swedish citizen, married to a non-EU national. We've been married over 3 years. My husband recently got a one-year visa, issued free of charge, by the German Embassy and we are currently in Sweden. I am moving to Germany in search of work, and would like my husband to travel and live with me in Germany.

Can he get his permit using the EU directive without leaving Germany? I read online that he could get it without a problem, but I am not sure what the procedure is.

Comment: What type of visa did your husband get?

Comment: He got a one year C Schengen visa that allows him to stay a maximum of 3 months. He's only spent a 2 weeks as at now.

Comment: He cannot get a residence card until you move to Germany.  Once you are in Germany, he'll have to go to the local Ausländerbehörde with the necessary documents.  Questions about relocation are off-topic here, though.  Ask at [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Also, as long as he is with you, the 90-day limit cannot be applied to him because when he is with you he is a "person enjoying freedom of movement" under EU law.